# element.scrollTop not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I am building a component which basically detects when the user has stopped scrolling. Then it finds the closes section tag on the page and smooth scrolls to the top of the section. I have it 95% done and working perfect on Chrome and Safari, however I cannot for the life of me get it to work properly on Firefox. My issue is that Firefox cant find the scrollTop value of the body tag. No matter what it always said the value is 0 or 1. When I read up on this issue I see a lot of fixes involving including document. before the body, but that just causes errors in my script. When I try to use other methods like pageOffsetY and jQuery I still get issues with my script. If you have any suggestions on resolving this issue that would be great. I am also open to changing my smooth scroll function to accommodate this fix, which I will provide below below. However the only thing is I need to be able to cancel the function if the user starts scrolling again and this is the only javascript one I can get to work that doesnt fight the user when the try to scroll while the function is running.

```
smooth_scroll_to(document.body, scrollPoint.y, 600);


var smooth_scroll_to = function(element, target, duration) {
    target = Math.round(target);
    duration = Math.round(duration);
    if (duration < 0) {
        return Promise.reject("bad duration");
    }
    if (duration === 0) {
        element.scrollTop = target;
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    var start_time = Date.now();
    var end_time = start_time + duration;

    var start_top = element.scrollTop;
    var distance = target - start_top;

    // based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothstep
    var smooth_step = function(start, end, point) {
        if(point <= start) { return 0; }
        if(point >= end) { return 1; }
        var x = (point - start) / (end - start); // interpolation
        return x*x*(3 - 2*x);
    }

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // This is to keep track of where the element's scrollTop is
        // supposed to be, based on what we're doing
        var previous_top = element.scrollTop;

        // This is like a think function from a game loop
        var scroll_frame = function() {
            if(element.scrollTop != previous_top) {
                reject("interrupted");
                return;
            }

            // set the scrollTop for this frame
            var now = Date.now();
            var point = smooth_step(start_time, end_time, now);
            var frameTop = Math.round(start_top + (distance * point));
            element.scrollTop = frameTop;

            // check if we're done!
            if(now >= end_time) {
                resolve();
                return;
            }

            // If we were supposed to scroll but didn't, then we
            // probably hit the limit, so consider it done; not
            // interrupted.
            if(element.scrollTop === previous_top
                && element.scrollTop !== frameTop) {
                resolve();
                return;
            }
            previous_top = element.scrollTop;

            // schedule next frame for execution
            setTimeout(scroll_frame, 0);
        }

        // boostrap the animation process
        setTimeout(scroll_frame, 0);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) instead of `document.body`:

```
smooth_scroll_to(document.documentElement, scrollPoint.y, 600);
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?